How can I import wasm in a webworker with Vite for a production build?
I am using vite and runnning @silvia-odwyer/photon in a webworker to do some image processing. I simply import with const photon = await import('@silvia-odwyer/photon'); in the webworker. I have been using vite-plugin-wasm for this, here is my vite config:
import wasm from 'vite-plugin-wasm';
import topLevelAwait from 'vite-plugin-top-level-await';

export default {
    plugins: [
        wasm(),
        topLevelAwait()
    ],
    worker: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                format: "iife",
                inlineDynamicImports: true,
            }
        },
        plugins: () => {
            return [wasm(), topLevelAwait()]
        }
    },
};

This works fine for the dev server, but the import doesn't seem to be working with a production build (using npm run build), photon just ends up being undefined. I have tried a bunch of different methods for importing, none of which worked. I hope somebody can help me because I'm pretty new to Wasm and Vite, and don't really know what else to try.

I've got the same problem, did you find a solution?

@Theiaz unfortunately I didn't find a solution, I ended up going back to using webpack for my project.

I think the problem you're facing could be your rollupOptions with iife format.
I've  experienced some similar issues when building for production with the provided example repository for this question. The solution was to change the the format of the worker to es. Maybe its helping you...
// vite.config.ts
...
  worker: {
    plugins: () => [wasm(), topLevelAwait()],
    format: 'es' // default is iife
  }

